# Installing 5.25'' optical drive in a peculiar case

Tags: repair

I want to install a 5.25" optical drive in a Chieftec BT-02B. The manufacturer advertises the presence of a 5.25 inside the case, and there is a 'flap' for the disk tray at the front, so I'm pretty sure it should be doable.

Yet, inside where the bay there is no mounting holes for the screws. I've looked at the 5.25" for factor spec, and there is no mention of alternative mounting strategies besides the standard screw holes.

So, how am I supposed to secure the drive in the bay?

Here are some pictures of the two sides of the drive bay.

[image: side A of the drive bay]
[image: side B of the drive bay]

Comment: There may be a screw on one side only (I have seen that) and the case holes may be on the top or bottom of the drive (inconvenient). You may see if you can adapt a side hole without damaging anything. I have done this too.

Comment: *"how am I supposed to secure the drive in the bay?"* -- Didn't the case include a pair of mounting rails, as shown in a photo at the [manufacturer' s web page](https://www.chieftec.eu/de/geh%C3%A4use/itx/uni-serie/bt-02b-u3.html)?  The inward-pointing flanges of the holes would be guides for those rails installed on a drive.  BTW installation of an optical drive would seem to compromise/interfere with the CPU fan.

Comment: Thanks for this. Indeed, it seems I'm missing the mounting rails (I got the case second hand and there were no such rails to be found).